# ExtJS won't send a 'destroy' command to server when calling remove on store

Tags: extjs, proxy, extjs4.1, record

The following is for ExtJS

So I'm trying the following in my view. (Basically deleting a record) But for some reason it won't even send a 'destroyRecord' call to the server at all. Any idea why this might be happening? Code below.

Note that module.getResults and module.destroyRecord below call the same function that creates the actual server call. module.getResults gets called properly and I get the record properly, but can't seem to get it to hit the 'destoryRecord' section. I'm wondering if it has to do with the hasMany param, but not positive. Any help would be beneficial.

View:

```
var record = this.down('form').getRecord();
var store = Ext.getStore('ModuleStore');
store.remove(record);
```

Store:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.store.ModuleStore', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

requires: [
    'MyApp.model.ModuleModel'
],

constructor: function(cfg) {
    var me = this;
    cfg = cfg || {};
    me.callParent([Ext.apply({
        autoLoad: true,
        autoSync: true,
        filterOnLoad: false,
        remoteFilter: true,
        remoteSort: true,
        sortOnLoad: false,
        storeId: 'module',
        model: 'MyApp.model.ModuleModel',
        buffered: true,
        listeners: {
            write: {
                fn: me.onStoreWrite,
                scope: me
            },
            remove: {
                fn: me.onStoreRemove,
                scope: me
            },
            datachanged: {
                fn: me.onStoreDataChangeD,
                scope: me
            }
        }
    }, cfg)]);
},

onStoreRemove: function(store, record, index, options) {
    console.log('remove'); // Isn't called for some reason
}

});
```

Model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.ModuleModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

uses: [
    'MyApp.model.ModuleHistoryModel'
],

idProperty: 'id',

fields: [
    {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'AmendmentNumber',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'contract_id',
        type: 'int'
    }
],

proxy: {
    type: 'direct',
    api: {
        create: module.createRecord,
        read: module.getResults,
        update: module.updateRecords,
        destroy: module.destroyRecord
},
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    }
},

hasMany: {
    model: 'MyApp.model.ModuleHistoryModel',
    foreignKey: 'Module_id',
    name: 'history'
}
});
```

ModuleHistory Model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.ModuleHistoryModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

uses: [
    'MyApp.model.MaintTypeModel'
],

fields: [
    {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'ContractNumber',
        type: 'string'
    },
    {
        name: 'MaintType_id',
        type: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'Module_id',
        type: 'int'
    }
],

proxy: {
    type: 'direct',
    api: {
        create: modulehistory.createRecord,
        read: modulehistory.getResults,
        update: modulehistory.updateRecords,
        destroy: modulehistory.destroyRecord
},
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    }
},

belongsTo: {
    associationKey: 'MaintType',
    model: 'MyApp.model.MaintTypeModel',
    getterName: 'getMaintType',
    foreignKey: 'MaintType_id',
    setterName: 'setMaintType'
}
});
```

MainType Model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.MaintTypeModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

idProperty: 'id',

fields: [
    {
        name: 'id',
        type: 'int'
    },
    {
        name: 'Type',
        type: 'string'
    }
],

proxy: {
    type: 'direct',
    api: {
        create: mainttype.createRecord,
        read: mainttype.getResults,
        update: mainttype.updateRecords,
        destroy: mainttype.destroyRecord
},
    reader: {
        type: 'json',
        root: 'data'
    }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call store sync aswell, so you sync your grid with the server.

```
var record = this.down('form').getRecord();
var store = Ext.getStore('ModuleStore');
store.remove(record);
store.sync();
```

I would send you the docs, but they seem to be down.

Comment: I shouldn't need to do a sync since I have the store setup as autosync to true. Does the autosync feature not work for remove? I thought it did...